# SQL updating one column based on certain criteria

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-update, criteria

I have a `SQL` table and within this table there is a `BIT` column `"IsComplete"` that needs to be set if other columns have data within them.

The `IsComplete` was originally handled by a checkbox in the application, and I want to transfer the responsibility to the `SQL DB` to handle setting this "`IsComplete`" column to true based on the following:

```
IsComplete = true if column1 = [something] and column2 = [something] and column3 = [something]
IsComplete = false if column1, column2 or column3 is null or = [nothing]
```

How do I accomplish this.

Comment: [something] is what, a field in some table on your db?

Comment: [something] means anything but NULL or Blank string, I wasn't sure how to state that easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could Also have a computed column for this.

Just create a Function to receive the 3 paranmeters and return True if 3 parameters are not null and else False.

Then Create the column IsCOmplete ,and set it in Computed Column Specification

In formula use dbo.Yourfunction(column1,column2,column3)

Answer (score 0):

You can just do a Update

```
Update tableBlah setComplete = 0

Update tableBlah setComplete = 1 where column1 = [something] and column2 = [something] and column3 = [something]
```

And have a trigger on that table to do the same when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your question, I think I'm missing something.
Anyway, if it's what I think, You can use Case statement

```
update T set IsComplete = CASE WHEN column1 = something and column2 = something
and column2 = something THEN 1 
WHEN column1 != [Something] OR column2 != [Something] OR column3 != [Something] THEN 0 END
from yourTable T --Your where criteria goes Here, if you need it
```

This answer consider that `yourTable` got 3 columns, and a column `Something`, and you will update `IsComplete` considering the values on each row

Comment: this will not work based on your comment to my answer what if `column1 = something2 and column2 = something2 and column3 = something3`?

Answer (score 0):

```
update Table SET IsComplete = ISNULL(DATALENGTH(COALESCE(col1,col2,col3)) % 1) + 1,0);
```

Should do the trick.

[What is coalesce](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx)

[What is isnull](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx)

[What is datalength](http://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/ms173486.aspx)

[What is %](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190279.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

Use Case

```
SET IsComplete = CASE 
WHEN NULLIF(column1,'') IS NULL OR NULLIF(column2,'') is null 
or NULLIF(column3,'') is null THEN 0 
ELSE 1   
END
```

Answer to your comment below for INSERT:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (IsComplete) 
SELECT CASE 
    WHEN NULLIF(@column1,'') IS NULL OR 
    NULLIF(@column2,'') is null or 
    NULLIF(@column3,'') is null THEN 0 
    ELSE 1     
    END
```

Comment: perform a select? can you explain

Comment: ah ok, I should have known that. Thank you everyone

Comment: I didn't downvote you. But your answer is incorrect, considering that he said in the first line that IsComplete is in a table that got more columns (and you're inserting in a table with one unique field). Also, you are updating and no considering [Something], only different of Null. And it could be posible that there are fields that are not null and not [Something] (considering this passed as a parameter from application)

Comment: he posted this to your comment below OP - `[something] means anything but NULL or Blank string`, I wasn't sure how to state that easily , your answer also doesn't consider `column1  = [something1] or column2 = something2`? Insert was sample code, he asked me how to do that for insert, he didn't ask question about how to insert in all columns